# change the 2nd column from positive to negative and vice versa

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

How can i change the 2nd column from positive to negative and vice versa

aa.txt

```
31OCT2013:00:00:00,220.10,"O","090500 13549951"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,-0.32,"I","090500 13549964"
```

Answer should be

aa.txt

```
31OCT2013:00:00:00,-220.10,"O","090500 13549951"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,+0.32,"I","090500 13549964"
```

If i use awk

```
'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2=-$2}1' aa.txt
```

the result is

```
1OCT2013:00:00:00,-220.1,"O","090500 13549951"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,+0.32,"I","090500 13549964"
```

In the first result, sign is changing but 0 is missing, instead of `-220.10`, it is showing as `-220.1`.

Comment: What do you mean? Please elaborate, may be with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you want to change the second column based on comma, this can be a way:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2=-$2}1' aa.txt
31OCT2013:00:00:00,-220.1,"O","090500 13549951"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,0.32,"I","090500 13549964"
```

See

```
31OCT2013:00:00:00,-220.1,"O","090500 13549951"
                   ^
31OCT2013:00:00:00,0.32,"I","090500 13549964"
                   ^
```

### Update

With the previous version we were losing trailing zeros, as per a arithmetic behaviour. To handle it properly, we can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {if ($2>0) $2="-"$2; else sub("-", "", $2)}1' file
```

In case the value is positive, it adds a dash in front of the string. Otherwise, it just deletes the dash.

Given a sample file

```
$ cat a
31OCT2013:00:00:00,220.10,"O","090500 13549951"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,-0.32,"I","090500 13549964"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,0.300,"I","090500 13549964"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,-0.300,"I","090500 13549964"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,0,"I","090500 13549964"
```

It returns

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {if ($2>0) $2="-"$2; else sub("-", "", $2)}1' a
31OCT2013:00:00:00,-220.10,"O","090500 13549951"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,0.32,"I","090500 13549964"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,-0.300,"I","090500 13549964"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,0.300,"I","090500 13549964"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,0,"I","090500 13549964
```

Comment: But the value os 0 is not appearing

31OCT2013:00:00:00,-220.1,"O","090500 13549951"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,0.32,"I","090500 13549964"


Input 
UATGRID$cat aa.txt
31OCT2013:00:00:00,220.10,"O","090500 13549951"
31OCT2013:00:00:00,-0.32,"I","090500 13549964"

Comment: @nkalis please update your question with more info. In comments it is not possible to see the text properly.

Comment: @nkalis ok, see my updated answer. It needed some tricks :) Now it is fine

Comment: This is giving a rather accurare result

Comment: Good to read that, @nkalis . In case your issue is solved you can accept the answer.

Comment: I have registered my account today, how can i accept the answer and vote for you

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*,\)-/\1/
t
s/^[^,]*,/&-/' YourFile
```

Based on `-` existance

Comment: If I use UATGRID$sed 's/^\([^,]*,\)-/\1/ts/^[^,]*,/&-/' aa.txt
sed: 0602-404 Function s/^\([^,]*,\)-/\1/ts/^[^,]*,/&-/ cannot be parsed.

Comment: there was a `'` not needed in first line of script. Corrected in post. This is posix compliant so maybe option `-posix` and in GNU sed `-e`. Work on my AIX sed

Comment: This might be a bit easier `sed 's/,-/,/;t;s/,/,-/' file`

Comment: right, work on his sample, i focus too far. The simpliest the best +1

Answer (score 0):

Use sprintf to format the output.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2=sprintf("%+.2f",-$2)}1' aa.txt
```

Comment: What if the second column is `-0.3000000`?

Comment: Then you would do it differently, but that's not the question that was asked. In the example, all the numbers have the same precision.